# if every thing should be enclosed in quotation mark, how to handle the bind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUnSubmit" Text="UnSubmit" CommandName="UnSubmit" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%# Eval("form_id") %> />
```

Actually it statement is correct, but according to W3C standard, every attributes should enclosed quotation in mark, so more correct way is

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnUnSubmit" Text="UnSubmit" CommandName="UnSubmit" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("form_id") %>" />
```

But you say the " signature will make some fault, could i ask how to solve it, even i change " inside the <%# %> to be \" , also cannot work out.

Comment: is that only one solution, actually i prefer to use " instead of ', but that is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'` (single quote) instead of `"` (double quote).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUnSubmit" Text="UnSubmit" CommandName="UnSubmit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("form_id") %>' />
```

For the most part the `"` and the `'` are interchangeable in HTML.

Comment: is that only one solution, actually i prefer to use " instead of ', but that is also fine

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("form_id") %>' />
```